# Printing stems back to stereo for international versions in Protools and the volume seems to be slightly higher...why is this?

Tags: audio, mixing, pro-tools, post-production

I'm doing what should be a simple mixdown of stems back onto a stereo track for the international version...stereo music stem, stereo sfx stem, mono narr stem and mono dial stem.  I've taken out the commercial blacks and bumpers and mixed the stems to smooth out the edits, but when I punch them into the pre-existing Full Mix, the volume is slightly higher.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: It's possible that the client delivered the wrong stems, but just wanted to rule out any error on my part...

Comment: For clarification, which parts are louder?  The new mix as a whole?  The stems within the mix?  The stems alone?

Comment: The stems that I'm combining to make the stereo Full Mix/Mix Minus tracks.  The client seems to have delivered the undipped stems for re-mixing, which seems totally weird to me, but that's what I have to work with!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a case of differing Pan laws between your software and theirs. Are any tracks panned and are these the sounds which appear louder?

It may be worth asking them which Panning law their software was set to and check either your options or DAW documentation to find out which one you are set to.

Here's a quick rundown on a Logic example: http://logicquicktips.blogspot.co.uk/2006/10/laws-of-pan.html